# AngularJS orderBy filter not working in currency

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**AngularJS** orderBy `filter` not working when use `orderBy : 'rate'` and the rest `date` and `product` works fine

```js
(function(){
var app = angular.module('tableApp',[ ]);
app.controller('tableController', function($scope){
 $scope.items = [
     { product: 'Lorem ipsum', date: '12-March-2013', rate:'12.35'},
     { product: 'dolor sit', date: '1-January-2011', rate:'60.54'},
     { product: 'consectetur', date: '12-December-2014', rate:'12.56'},
     { product: 'adipisicing', date: '14-Noveber-2014', rate:'0.99'},
     { product: 'do eiusmod', date: '2-Noveber-2014', rate:'4.001'},
     { product: 'magna aliqua', date: '16-February-2014', rate:'06.54'},
     { product: 'exercitation', date: '30-Noveber-2014', rate:'60.32'},
     { product: 'consequat', date: '5-May-2014', rate:'5.12'},
     { product: 'reprehenderit', date: '12-April-2014', rate:'8.99'},
     { product: 'voluptate', date: '18-Noveber-2014', rate:'34.54'},
     { product: 'ugiat nulla', date: '28-June-2014', rate:'55.12'},
     { product: 'occaecat cupidatat', date: '21-June-2014', rate:'99.54'},
     { product: 'proident', date: '31-December-2014', rate:'15.50'},
     { product: 'culpa qui', date: '1-Noveber-2014', rate:'34.05'},
     { product: 'mollit anim', date: '3-Noveber-2014', rate:'45.00'}
 ]
});
})();
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="tableApp">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover" ng-controller="tableController">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy : 'rate'">
        <td>{{item.product}}</td>
        <td>{{item.date}}</td>
        <td>{{item.rate | currency:"£"}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Surely you created this code as an example, but just in case: note there is a typo in Nove(m)ber ;)

Comment: @Pablo yah, just testing purpose only. By the way thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The attribute `rate` is a String, so `orderBy : 'rate'` sorts them as Strings (which is totally working).

If you want to sort them correctly, you should remove quotes around the rate value (so they will be sorted as Numbers).

Like this:

```
{ product: 'mollit anim', date: '3-Noveber-2014', rate: 45.00 }
```

Also, remove the `0` in `06.54`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ruytehtc/ (Same HTML, removed quotes and leading `0`)

Comment: I misunderstood your quotes thing, I thought you meant on the filter itself. Deleted mine and upvoted yours. JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ruytehtc/

Comment: OK, no problem. I didn't saw your comment and I rewrite the exact same jsfiddle. =D

Comment: How to orderBy date ?

Comment: I think you have to put dates in a standard format such as JS `Date` or maybe ISO 8601 (`"2014-11-27T12:57:19.524Z"`) (used when you jsonize a `Date`).

Comment: @BinaryBrain This link might be helpful https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 1):

you can try out this....

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function(){
var app = angular.module('tableApp',[ ]);
app.controller('tableController', function($scope){
    $scope.items = [
        { product: 'Lorem ipsum', date: '12-March-2013', rate:12.35},
        { product: 'dolor sit', date: '1-January-2011', rate:60.54},
        { product: 'consectetur', date: '12-December-2014', rate:12.56},
        { product: 'adipisicing', date: '14-November-2014', rate:0.99},
        { product: 'do eiusmod', date: '2-November-2014', rate:4.001},
        { product: 'magna aliqua', date: '16-February-2014', rate:6.54},
        { product: 'exercitation', date: '30-November-2014', rate:60.32},
        { product: 'consequat', date: '5-May-2014', rate:5.12},
        { product: 'reprehenderit', date: '12-April-2014', rate:8.99},
        { product: 'voluptate', date: '18-November-2014', rate:34.54},
        { product: 'ugiat nulla', date: '28-June-2014', rate:55.12},
        { product: 'occaecat cupidatat', date: '21-June-2014', rate:99.54},
        { product: 'proident', date: '31-December-2014', rate:15.50},
        { product: 'culpa qui', date: '1-November-2014', rate:34.05},
        { product: 'mollit anim', date: '3-November-2014', rate:45.00}
    ]
});
})();
</script>
</head>
```

you just change your array with this array it will definitely work..